# array_flip certain keys

Tags: php, arrays

What would be a good way of fliping key 1 with key 2?

```
// original
Array
(
    [0] => Text1
    [1] => World
    [2] => Hello
)

// after

Array
(
    [0] => Text1
    [1] => Hello
    [2] => World
)
```

Any clues. Thanks

Comment: BTW, array_flip() isn't what you are looking for. It switches key with value, whereas you want to change the order of your array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a simple as that,

```
$tmp = $array[1];
$array[1] = $array[2];
$array[2] = $tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$A = array("Text1", "Hello", "World");
$tmp = $A[2];
$A[2] = $A[1];
$A[1] = $tmp;
```